# Ad Hoc Validation on checkboxlist yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have an activeForm with a model

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dynamicModel, 'brands')->checkboxList($brands); ?>
...
```

I'm also using ajax validation
Now I want to add validation to the checkboxlist

I found this: http://www.yiiframew...-hoc-validation
and this: http://www.yiiframew...hvalidator.html

But I have no idea how to use it

And how to I assign the values to the dynamic model?
It's from a junctiontable, I know how to get them from the database, but not how to assign them

```
$dynamicModel = \yii\base\DynamicModel::validateData(['brands'], [
    [['brands'], 'required'],
    ['brands', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess this would help you:

```
// controller code:

$dynamicModel = new DynamicModel();
$dynamicModel->defineAttribute('brands', $value = null);

$dynamicModel->addRule(['brands'], 'required']);
$dynamicModel->addRule(['brands', 'each', ['rule' => ['integer']]]);

// load with the submitted post data
$dynamicModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

// validation
$dynamicModel->validate();


// view code
<?= $form->field($dynamicModel, 'brands')->checkboxList(['1'=>'brand 1', '2'=>'brand 2']) ?>
```